# Is there a shortcut for double de-reference followed by a dot operation?

Tags: c++

While
    `var->atr` 
is a shortcut for 
    `(*var).atr` 

Is there a shortcut for
`(*var)->atr`
which is the same as
`(*(*var)).atr`
`(**var).atr`

Perhaps something like a longer arrow?
`var-->.atr`

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: `var[0]->atr`? I think `(*var)->atr` is the better looking one. But it's just a style thing.

Comment: For your "longer arrow" idea, see [What is the “-->” operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c). For your double de-reference issue, I'd advise seeking ways around needing it, which might make your code easier to read as a side-benefit.

Comment: Maybe, `#define dr(pp) (*(pp))->`... and use it like: `dr(var)atr` ?

Comment: As a historical note, this shows the mistake of having made the `*` dereference operator a prefix operator. If it had been a suffix operator, (a) we wouldn't need the `->` operator at all, and (b) you would have been able to write `var**.atr`. Of course a different symbol would have had to be used, as in Pascal's `^`, which in turn is enabled by it having the `xor` keyword.

Comment: Ya, I guess `*` as a post-fix was reserved for multiplication, it's unfortunate they were unable to come up with another symbol to use. I suppose the `.` operator has precedence over dereference, hence requiring parenthesis `(*var).atr`. `var*.atr` and `var**.atr` would make it so easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no shortcut for two levels of indirection.  We have to do either `(**var).atr`, or `(*var)->atr`.

If you really have a lot of levels of indirection, you may use a function template:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) deref(T&& t)
{
    if constexpr (N == 0) {
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    } else {
        return *deref<N - 1>(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
}
```

so that `deref<10>(x).member` means `(**********x).member`.  I won't recommend this though.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize you could do `(**var).atr` , `(*(*var)).atr` is messy. I had no plans to use more than 2 levels of indirection, but that function template does look interesting!